# How do I get blender to stop creating so many files?

Tags: file-format, blend-files, file-browser

I have a problem naming files. I tend to name them crazy things because I don't feel like naming them properly when in a hurry.

Anyways, I am very used to photoshop, and just about every other program out there when it comes to saving things. With blender, I save a file, and choose to overwrite the blend file, but for some reason it creates a blend1, or a blend11, or some other crazy combination of blend.blend1.blend, etc.

All I want is to be able to save my file with one name. If I want to save that file as a different name to make a copy, I'd like to just do a "Save As" to save it with an alternative name.

My desktop is FILLED with orange blender icons! If anyone could help me get this working the way I described I'd really appreciate it. I'm very new to blender.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Any file with ".blend" and then a number is a backup file created by blender. This is not related to *Save* or *Save As*, which act the same as other program's implementations of them. Every time you save, the previous saved version gets loaded into ".blend1", so these extra files are your previous saves. If you ever wanted to use one of these previous saves you would rename the extension back to ".blend" and open it.

In Blender **2.9** you can go to *Edit> Preferences> Save & Load* and set *Save Versions* to 0 if you don't want these extra backup files:

In **2.79**, *Save Versions* is found via *File> User Preferences> File*:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for saving me icon space!

Comment: Also click "save user settings"...

Comment: I would not leave save versions at 0, for easy disaster recovery.
May I suggest you to not save files on your desktop as well?

If decluttering is your main objective, consider creating a dedicated "projects" folder in your documents, with one subfolder for each individual project.

I promise it will be useful even when you start working with textures, animations with multiple frames to render, simulation caches and reference pictures for a specific job!

Comment: Now located in Preferences > Save & Load > Save Versions to 0

Comment: @Robbie Thanks, updated.